# Blue screen due Windows IoT Core 10 B+ loading

Tags: raspberry-pi3, boot, windows-iot-core-10

I try to run Windows IoT Core 10 B+ over Raspberry Pi 3 B+.
The plate is new. The OS I downloaded from here: [Windows IoT 10 B+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot), I used:
`RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661`

I user [this](https://www.hackster.io/JiongShi/windows-10-iot-core-for-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-92b1a3) manual to install the OS to teh flash.

I have 4 INCH HDMI LCD with Touch Pad connected to the plate.
For connect the LCD I was need to modify original config (`g:\config.txt`) file - see code below.
But the problem not in config, when I use original config, I have no device detected in Dashboard. If I use modified config, I have monitor working, but have blue screen.

I have follow drives after FFU uploading:

- USB Drive F:
- EFIESP G:
- MainOS H:
- Data J:

I searched for logs and important files, and didn't found much:

- j:\FirstBoot.Complete

Some DUMP like files, however, it is **unable** to open it in Visual Studio as DUMP files:

- j:\DUMP0c15.tmp
- j:\DUMP0c35.tmp
- j:\DedicatedDumpFile.sys

Follow directories, however it are empty:

- j:\Logfiles\WMI\RtBackup\
- j:\CrashDump\
- h:\Windows\tracing\
- h:\Windows\LiveKernelReports\
- h:\Windows\system32\winevt\Logs\

The modified content of: `g:\config.txt`:

```
init_uart_clock=16000000    # Set UART clock to 16Mhz
kernel_old=1                # Load kernel.img at physical memory address 0x0
safe_mode_gpio=8            # A temp firmware limitation workaround
max_usb_current=1           # Enable maximum usb current
gpu_mem=32                  # Set VC to 32MB, ARM DRAM to (1008-32)MB
hdmi_force_hotplug=1        # Enable HDMI display even if it is not connected (640x480)
core_freq=250               # Frequency of GPU processor core in MHz
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1  # Ignore the alpha channel for Windows.
framebuffer_swap=1          # Set the frame buffer to be Windows BGR compatible.
disable_overscan=1          # Disable overscan
hdmi_group=2                # Use VESA Display Mode Timing over CEA
hdmi_mode=87                 # 5 inch screen
hdmi_cvt 480 800 60 6 0 0 0  # 5 inch screen
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
display_rotate=3
```

This is screenshot of blue screen:

[image: Blue screen]

As I see, there is notification about: `BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO`

I read [troubleshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/troubleshooting) and some other information.
I have follow questions:

- What are the drives responsible for: `G:`, `F:`, `J:`, `H:` ?
- Where can I find boot logs in the Windows IoT file system?
- Where can I find more documentation about Windows IoT OS architecture and its system's directory tree?
- What can be the problem?

PS: I **have** successful expirianse to run Windows IoT Core 10 on Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: May be it is better to post it to Server Fault, or Raspberry community? But I don't see option to migrate the question...

Comment: I opened question there:https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94238/blue-screen-due-windows-iot-core-10-b-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note there is **no official release** version of Windows IoT Core for Raspberry Pi 3**B+**. There is only one insider preview version 17761 suppose to working on 3B+. So use the image you download without any modification to see if it works.

> But th eproblem not in config, when I use original config, I have to
>   device detected in Dashboard. If I use modified config, I have monitor
>   working, but have blue screen.

If you mean you can't detected the device in Dashboard please connect a display via HDMI to see the system boot up or not. For me "BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO" seems due to you change the default settings so cause the system boot fails.

> What are the drives responsible for: G:, F:, J:, H: ?

MainOS: OS and OEM-preloaded apps.

EFI: Fixed-size partition with the boot manager, boot configuration database.

Data: User data partition, user registry hives, apps, apps data.

More detailed information please refer to "[IoT Device Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/device-layout)".

> Where can I find boot logs in the Windows IoT file system?

You may need use [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/windowsdebugger#raspberry-pi-2-or-3-rpi2-or-rpi3) to get boot information when the system can boot up successfully.

> Where can I find more documentation about Windows IoT OS architecture
>   and its system's directory tree?

It seem no such dedicated document. But you can reference the following documents:

["Windows kernel"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/_kernel/), ["Architecture of Windows 10"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31048.architecture-of-windows-10.aspx), ["An overview of Windows 10 IoT"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot), ["Windows file sharing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/windowsfilesharing)

Windows IoT Core is a Windows 10 edition for IoT. It has many commonalities with Windows 10 other editions and has some limitations due to its device limited resource. So you can compare Windows 10 IoT Core and a full version Windows 10 like Windows 10 IoT Enterprise to understand it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was misspelled: "But the problem not in config, when I use original config, I have no device detected in Dashboard". Thank you for answers despite my misspelling ) You help me very much!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/device-layout Wonderful! I was need it ) And thank you for all other link too! )

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova You're welcome and glad to help.